# Indefinite article before an adjective in form [number]-[something]

Tags: articles

Which one of these is correct?

- *We use two-stage compilation process.*
- *We use a two-stage compilation process.*

The second looks more formally correct, but feels strange.

Perhaps this is better?

- *We use two-stage compilation.*

Comment: The first one would be grammatical if _process_ were pluralized to _processes_; but in the singular, the article is required. The simpler alternative at the end is better, though -- if compilation isn't a process, I don't know what is, so there's no reason to burden yourself with a category label for it. Plus _compilation_ can be either mass or count, so articles are optional.

Comment: This question looks familiar. Did you ask this a few days ago and delete it?

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence is definitely correct. However, as John Lawler points out in a comment above, if the sentence was pluralised, the first one would be correct:

> We use two-stage compilation process**es**.